# Can I add expand and collapse for a specific data in the auto generated emails I trigger? If Yes, how?

Tags: c#, email, automation, mtm, ranorex

Auto generated emails are triggered every day morning after my automation runs through Ranorex. Till now only the count of passed and failed test cases are displayed along with the failed test case titles. I am trying to add the steps also which are failed in that particular test case if it is failed as we designed it in a way where test run doesn't stop if one step is failed. This will be awesome if only few test steps are failed in the test case, But if all are failed, the mail might be annoying. So I wanted to add the expand and collapse way there for this specific data.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question was already answered in the Ranorex forum. A Ranorex engineer posted a code snippet which adds failure messages into the report.
http://www.ranorex.com/forum/custom-report-log-t3920.html#p26749